# Bold font error

Tags: fontspec, bold

When I type the `ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS` page using bold font, the following text is still bold while it should be normal (not bold). I used this code:

```
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\thepage}  % Sets the right side header to show the page number
\addtolength{\voffset}{0.07in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}
\begin{center}{\normalsize{\bf ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS} \par}\end{center}
{\normalsize
\vspace*{0.35\baselineskip}
\setstretch{0.95}
  First, I am grateful to GOD bla bla bla }
\clearpage  % Declaration ended, now start a new page
\cleardoublepage
```

Comment: Please post a complete document that shows the problem, The bold fornt you have there is scoped by the braces, so your problem is in code not shown. Unrelated ut you shoul dnot use `\bf` in laTeX, `\begin{center}{\normalsize{\bf ACKNOWLEDGMENTS} \par}\end{center}` should be `\begin{center}\normalsize\bfseries ACKNOWLEDGMENTS\end{center}`

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least 4 main ways to have some text in bold:

- `\textbf{`Bold text is here`}`
- `{\bfseries` Bold text is here`}`
- `\bfseries` Bold text is here `\mdseries`
- `\begin{bfseries}` Bold text is here `\end{bfseries}`

As said by David Carlisle, you should not use `\bf` but `\bfseries` instead.

Comment: Yes, your answer was more than perfect. Thank you, I used the third option of your answer.

Comment: @Montadar Use neither the third option, nor the fourth. The first is to be preferred, without any doubt.